# How to test specific method with maven-surefire-plugin in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, testing

I know use "mvn -Dtest=TestCircle#mytest test" can do that in console but i want to do in eclipse something like i select a method and right click than run, just like this.

I had tried to use eclipse variable to setup the test command parameters but there is no variable that can return a class name and method name what i have selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I know use "mvn -Dtest=TestCircle#mytest test" can do that in console
>   but i want to do in eclipse something like i select a method and right
>   click than run, just like this.

In eclipse you can just select the method you want to test in the package explorer and select right click -> Run As -> JUnit Test (see picture).

[image]

Nothing to do with Maven then anymore, though.